# Horizontal Lines in Dynamic Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, jstree

I have a need to develop a vertical navigation menu using a jQuery library that will give it treeview capabilities. The trick I'm running into problems with is that the menu needs to be multiline (ie word-wrap: normal on each anchor) and have horizontal lines running through it. Every method that I have tried makes either the lines appear oddly or the open/close icons for the treeview display incorrectly. I need IE6+ compatibility as well.

I'm using the jsTree jQuery library for the treeview and applying my own CSS to the mix. I've tried 4 different methods of getting it to work but [here is my current attempt](http://devwww.uaa.alaska.edu/stackOverflowTest.html). Viewing it in Firefox or IE8 produces the best results, but other browsers have various issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#leftnav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

It's just a basic white border on the bottom of each `<li>` entry.  It's very simple, but that's how I'd probably do it.  Depending on your choice of `<li>` background color, you might want to vary the border color.  You could even do this as you define the style and background of each level of `<li>` tag.

Comment: Using a bottom border unfortunately produces the same problems as the other solutions I've tried. The main issue is having them appear under each list-item while still retaining the indentation of children. My current workaround is to remove the padding/margin for all list items and then indenting the child icons & anchors, but IE browsers before 8 are really disliking this method.